# Should navigator stack be kept on a separated file or inside store?

Tags: react-native, redux

I started studying ReactNative recently and started building a simple application to test some concepts. The `Navigator` component is responsible for keeping track of navigation throughout the app, but I'm having some trouble defining a location for the variable that keeps that info.

I could keep it on a separated file, importing it as necessary, or I could keep it inside `state` (using `redux`). I believe the former is the best approach, since the latter would have a conceptual conflict: `push` and `pop` would change the state instead of replacing it with a new instance. Nevertheless, the scene I'm currently at fits within what should be kept inside state.

Is this understanding correct? Are there better approaches on the matter?

ps: So far I've only been testing on Android.